# CreateProcess doesn't work with error 2

Tags: c, windows, createprocess

I need to use the CreateProcess function but it doesn't work.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

    // Start the child process.
    if( !CreateProcess( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
        argv[1],        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    )
    {
        printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
        return 0;
    }

    // Wait until child process exits.
    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );

    // Close process and thread handles.
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
    return 0;
}
```

My executable and process to launch in executable are in the same folder:
Executable: Windows_Creating_Process.exe
Process: Ivcon.exe

So in command prompt I execute

```
Windows_Creating_Process.exe Ivcon.exe
```

in the folder containing them.

But it returns:

```
CreateProcess failed (2)
```

which corresponds to:

> ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
>   2 (0x2)
>   The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you. The other similar question answered my question, but not completely because there is a conflict between MSDN function and QTCreator. I explained how to solve that in this other question.